# How to make constant UI in English and Arabic in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am making one  application which can support English and Arabic language. My almost all code is done but now i am facing one problem that  ,when i run application setting  English language it looks great,but for arabic my UI get distrubed because English language has left allignment and Arabic has right allignment by default....what to do now ??please any one have idea then please help me.....waiting for reply

Comment: You'll need to post some images or have a better description cause I don't know what you mean when you say Arabic doesn't look good. Is it the alignment? Are you writing a native app or a browser based app?

Comment: @Tamar Yes my allignment of all component is changing when i set language to Arabic and UI distrubed

Answer (score 0):

If it's about right align UI elements - use the [Field.RIGHT](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#FIELD_HCENTER) style to have your components right align. It is left aligned by default. If you are using a HorizontalFieldManager you will also want to set the style for the scroll direction to be [LEFTWARD](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#LEFTWARD).

To set the style pass in these in the components constructor OR'ed, so:

```
new myField(Field.RIGHT | Manager.LEFTWARD);
```

Use the [Locale](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29) object to determine which language is currently set and set the alignment based on it.

Comment: just one language to be seen at a time, and that language is depend on language selection of device, if that is English or any language all info of application will be in English and if device language is Arabic application info must seen in Arabic.but this is i done already.....
But problem about alignments of my component because i set setMargin( ) to so much components by considering only English language and now because of that when i change language of device to Arabic UI gets disturbed for Arabic.this is the problem.i can't set constant UI to both Arabic and English language.....

Comment: This is correct, you cannot set a constant UI that will look good for both. That is what I meant, you need to set the values above depending on the device language. you can use the Locale object to determine which language is currently set: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29

Comment: ok i understood what you mean.But as there are 50-60 screens it will take double time to make this UI for Arabic again.but also thanks is something easy to this option then tell me otherwise i will take this as last option

Comment: Yeah, I hear your pain :) What you could do is check once when you start the app and set a final static boolean, then extend the Managers and Fields classes (LabelFiel, VerticalFieldManager etc.) and set the orientation in the constructor based on that boolean. In your app use only your custom objects. That way it's all in one place... I haven't tried LWUIT so I can't say if that will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

**APPROACH:** Using third party library

Have a look at [Arabic](https://picasaweb.google.com/100713690778808155023/LWUITPhotos#5615065768518014210) and [English](https://picasaweb.google.com/100713690778808155023/LWUITPhotos#5670260866422594498).

[LWUIT UI library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html) is pretty easy to create a common UI for both left-to-right and right-to-left languages. It might sound an uphill task now but going forward you will need to

- support multiple ODM's
- multipe screen device resolution
- multiple flavors of VM, etc

LWUIT library resolves all these problems and to top it the library source code is licensed under [GPLv2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) with the [classpath exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception). This essentially means you can use this library in your commercial projects. It is supports most mordern Blackberry OS's.

Comment: by using LWUIT library i have to make all 50-60 screens again that is too hectic